# How can I sum x number of table columns based on a parameter?

Tags: sql, loops, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Let's say I have table `budget` with 13 columns - `account` and `period01` through `period12`.

If I wanted to create a stored procedure that would return the sum of period01 through periodX (where X is passed as a parameter), how would I go about doing this?

In VBA, I solved this problem by creating a simple string parser that would build the SQL command for me. However, I am trying to cut out that layer and do this all from within a stored procedure at database level. Is there a more optimal way to do this, side from string parsing and CASE statements?

Comment: What version of TSQL?

Comment: @Shawn SQL Server 2012 (11.0.6251)

Comment: Why are you recording different periods in additional columns and not additional rows with a single 'PeriodNum' column for filtering?

Comment: @iamdave the table was automatically generated via importing of an excel file that was being used for a database. and because as it is designed now, it will continue to be updated from that data source, i don't think the structure can be changed to become easier to work with

Comment: @iamdave apparently what i said was not true at all, and our database guy has adjusted the script that creates the table structure. thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is why you shouldn't store columns pivoted like that.  It would be much simpler to handle this if each "period" column were on a separate row.

To get you started, here is a query that does what you want:

```
select b.*, @x, running.periodsum
from budget b outer apply
     (select sum(v.period) as periodsum
      from (values (1, b.period1), (2, b.period2), . . . (12, b.period12)) v(n, period)
      where v.n <= @x
     ) running;
```

And you don't have to make this a stored procedure.  You can make this a user-defined table function.

Comment: That's a pretty slick answer. I was thinking of an `UNPIVOT` with some sort of grouping for the sums, but I always forget that `OUTER APPLY` and `FROM VALUES()` can do some cool stuff.

Comment: wow! this solution was miles above my head and even had the in-office 'sql god' stumped. nice!